# Show Woocommerce subcategories on single page by their parents slug or ID

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook, categories, woocommerce-theming

I am trying to add Publisher, Topic and Author to a Single Product with help of categories/subcategories. This is how it looks after hours of coding/and copying (very fresh with WooCommerce tbh) [image: look of the current state]

This is what I am getting, but it shows ALL subcategories, not only the ones associated to the Product, this is the code I am using

```
    function get_product_subcategories_list( $category_slug ){
    $terms_html = array();
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
    // Get the product category (parent) WP_Term object
    $parent = get_term_by( 'slug', $category_slug, $taxonomy );
    // Get an array of the subcategories IDs (children IDs)
    $children_ids = get_term_children( $parent->term_id, $taxonomy );

    // Loop through each children IDs
    foreach($children_ids as $children_id){
        $term = get_term( $children_id, $taxonomy ); // WP_Term object
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy ); // The term link
        if ( is_wp_error( $term_link ) ) $term_link = '';
        // Set in an array the html formated subcategory name/link
        $terms_html[] = '<a href="' . esc_url( $term_link ) . '" rel="tag" class="' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
    }
    return '<span class="subcategories-' . $category_slug . '">' . implode( ', ', $terms_html ) . '</span>';
}
    add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','monolith_cat_scan', 31);
        function monolith_cat_scan() {
        echo '<p>Topic : ';
            echo get_product_subcategories_list( 'topics' );
        echo '</p>';
        echo '<p>Publisher : ';
              echo get_product_subcategories_list( 'publishers' );
        echo '</p>';
        echo '<p>Author: ';
              echo get_product_subcategories_list( 'authors' );
        echo '</p>';
        }
```

But I can't get the whole thing to work like I want to and get the subcategories of the Single Product, in this example only Spirituality, SOUNDS TRUE INC (only sub cat in Publishers), and Allan Watts should be there.

I'd appreciate every help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a working code (it doesn't look beautiful I know but it's the best I could do and it does the trick.

```
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','monolith_cat_scan', 31);

function monolith_cat_scan() {

global $post;

$cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {

        foreach ( $cats as $term ) {

        if( $term->parent == 30 ) { 
      echo '<p>Topic : <a href="' . site_url() . '/product-category/' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
   }

        }

}

}
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','monolith_cat_scan2', 32);

function monolith_cat_scan2() {

global $post;

$cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {

        foreach ( $cats as $term ) {

        if( $term->parent == 31 ) { 
      echo '<p>Author : <a href="' . site_url() . '/product-category/' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
   }

        }

}

}

add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','monolith_cat_scan3', 33);

function monolith_cat_scan3() {

global $post;

$cats = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );

if ( ! empty( $cats ) ) {

        foreach ( $cats as $term ) {

   // If parent cat ID = 116 echo subcat name...
        if( $term->parent == 32 ) { 
      echo '<p>Publisher : <a href="' . site_url() . '/product-category/' . $term->slug . '">' . $term->name . '</a>';
   }

        }

}

}
```